# Creating R loop to read in shapefiles from a directory and perform zonal statistics on each

Tags: r, for-loop, gis, lapply

I have 120 county shapefiles in a directory "Counties". I want to use R to read in each shapefile and, for each shapefile, perform zonal statistics (mean) using a single raster layer "NOAA_normal_crop."

I was able to create a script that reads in all of the shapefiles as a list:

```
library(rgdal)
library(raster)
library(sf)
library(maptools)

NOAA_normal <- raster("C:/path/to/raster/noaa_normal.tif")

input_path <- "C:/path/to/Counties"
files <- list.files(dir, pattern="[.]shp$", full.names=TRUE)
allShapes <- lapply(files, readOGR)
```

But I still need to create a loop that goes through each individual shapefile and performs the zonal statistics. The loop below is one I tried, but it only gives me a single value in return whereas I want the mean value for each polygon.

```
for (i in 1:length(allShapes)){
  ex <- extract(NOAA_normal_crop, allShapes[[i]], fun=mean, na.rm=TRUE, df=TRUE)
}
```

EDIT: I have also tried using lapply again, but this isn't working either.

```
lapply(allShapes, extract(NOAA_normal_crop, allShapes, fun=mean, na.rm=TRUE, df=TRUE))
# Error in round(y) : non-numeric argument to mathematical function
```

Thanks in advance for any advice you might have.

Comment: You know about `lapply`.  Why not use it again here?

Comment: I'd be happy to see an example using lapply, as well. Using the loop above was the closest I could get.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe your loop is correct. However it is not a list or array, so every iteration the value is being overwritten.
You should try:

`ex = vector()
for (i in 1:length(allShapes)){
    ex[i] <- extract(NOAA_normal_crop, allShapes[[i]], fun=mean, na.rm=TRUE, df=TRUE)
}`

Comment: This works if I remove the "df=TRUE". It returns a list of calculated values. Thank you, that is definitely a move in the right direction! Do you know if there's a way to keep it in a dataframe (preferably so I can tell which value is associated with the individual polygons)? The error I receive when leaving in df=TRUE is "In ex[i] <- extract(NOAA_normal_crop, allShapes[[i]],  ... :
  number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length".