# Modify a loop in R to add file name next to computed value

Tags: r, loops, gis, lapply

This is a continuation of a previous question: [Creating R loop to read in shapefiles from a directory and perform zonal statistics on each](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58187021/creating-r-loop-to-read-in-shapefiles-from-a-directory-and-perform-zonal-statist)

Original question answered by you nice folks, now I have another.

So, I have 120 county shapefiles in a directory "Counties". I'm using R to read in each shapefile and, for each shapefile, perform zonal statistics (mean) using a single raster layer "RGB_band1_NOAA."

Here is the code that performs the loop:

```
library(rgdal)
library(raster)
library(sf)
library(maptools)

input_path <- "C:/path/to/Counties"
files <- list.files(input_path, pattern="[.]shp$", full.names=TRUE)
allShapes <- lapply(files, readOGR)

observations = vector()
for (i in 1:length(allShapes)){
  observations[i] <- extract(RGB_band1_NOAA, allShapes[[i]], fun=mean, na.rm=TRUE)
}

> observations
[1] 0.0420572431 0.0000000000 0.0000000000 0.0000000000 0.0067861584 0.0004686914 0.0700653942 
 0.0000000000 0.0000000000 0.0542978996 0.0000000000
[12] 0.0000000000 0.0071916012 0.0000000000 0.0000000000 0.0000000000 0.0000000000 0.0000000000 0.0000000000 0.0000000000 0.0000000000 0.0323350977
[23] 0.0015185602 0.0000000000 0.0000000000 0.1012598426 0.0000000000 0.0000000000 0.0069525885....
```

This puts all of the results into a list. Is there a way to edit my loop performing the zonal statistics such that, for each computed value, R also adds the shapefile name next to it? In the folder, each shapefile is the county name (ex - Adair.shp, Boyd.shp). That way I can ensure that as I'm going through later (plan is to convert to dataframe with county names next to the value), each computed value matches up to the county it's associated with?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
names(observations)<-files
```

That should do the trick.

Or you might want to use only the filenames without the full path:

```
names(observations)<-list.files(input_path, pattern="[.]shp$")
```

This will give you a named vector. If you want to make this into a data.frame with two columns, you can use something like this:

```
observations<-data.frame(observations,filename=list.files(input_path, pattern="[.]shp$"),stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
```

Finally, if for some reason you insist on doing this internally to the loop, you can do this:

```
for (i in 1:length(allShapes)){
  observations[i] <- extract(RGB_band1_NOAA, allShapes[[i]], fun=mean, na.rm=TRUE)
  names(observations)[i]<-files[i]
}
```